# Shiny app using fluidrow and columns has overflow issues

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am using fluid row and columns layout in a shiny app. When I reduce the screen size the elements in two columns overlap. If they are two different columns and using fluid row shouldn't the contents overlap. Below is the code. I have two columns with width 4 and 8. They seem to be working fine in regular screen size but as soon as I minimize the window they overlap.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Bootstrap scrollspy on multiple tabs",
  id = "navbar",
  header = div(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs("www/app-shinyjs.js", functions = c("updateScrollspy")),
    includeCSS("www/app.css"),
    includeScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.3/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
  ),

  # tab 1 contains 4 sections and a scrollspy on the left with text
  tabPanel(
    "tab1",
    div(id = "tab1-content",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            4,
            div(
              id = "tab1-scrollspy",
              class = "potential-scrollspy",
              tags$ul(
                class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked",
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-1", "Section 1-1")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-2", "Section 1-2")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-3", "Section 1-3")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section1-4", "Section 1-4"))
              )
            )
          ),
          column(
            8,
            div(id = "section1-1",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-1')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-2",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-2')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-3",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-3')
            ),
            div(id = "section1-4",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 1-4')
            )              
          )
        )
    )
  ),

  # tab 2 contains 3 sections and a scrollspy on the right without text
  tabPanel(
    "tab2",
    div(id = "tab2-content",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            8,
            div(id = "section2-1",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-1')
            ),
            div(id = "section2-2",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-2')
            ),
            div(id = "section2-3",
                class = "scrollspy-section",
                p('Section 2-3')
            )
          ),
          column(
            4,
            div(
              id = "tab2-scrollspy",
              class = "potential-scrollspy",
              `data-offset` = 50,
              tags$ul(
                class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked",
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-1")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-2")),
                tags$li(tags$a(href = "#section2-3"))
              )
            )
          )
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # when changing tabs, update the scrollspy control
  observeEvent(input$navbar, {
    js$updateScrollspy(input$navbar)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screen size reduced :
[image]

```js
// initialize common scrollspy control
shinyjs.init = function() {
  $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.active-scrollspy' });
}

// update the active scrollspy control and refresh so that it will function
shinyjs.updateScrollspy = function(tab) {
  // make all scrollspy controls inactive
  $('active-scrollspy').removeClass('active-scrollspy');
  // get the content in the current tab
  var $tabContent = $('#' + tab + '-content');
  if ($tabContent.length) {
    // find the scrollspy control in the current tab
    var $scrollspy = $tabContent.find('.potential-scrollspy');
    if ($scrollspy.length) {
      // mark the scrollspy in the current tab as active
      $scrollspy.addClass('active-scrollspy');
      // figure out the offset for this scrollspy
      var offset = 0;
      if ($scrollspy.data('offset')) {
        offset = $scrollspy.data('offset');
      }
      // update the scrollspy object
      $('body').data('bs.scrollspy').options.offset = offset;
      $('body').scrollspy('refresh');
      // unbind click events and re-bind clicks to animate scrolling
      $scrollspy.unbind('click.scrollto');
      $scrollspy.bind('click.scrollto', 'ul li a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo(event.target.hash, 500, {
          offset: -offset
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#tab1-content .scrollspy-section {
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
#tab1-scrollspy {
position: fixed;
}
#tab1-scrollspy li > a {
background-color: #FFF;
  }
#tab1-scrollspy li > a:hover {
background-color: #EEE;
  }
#tab1-scrollspy li.active > a {
background-color: #AAA;
  }
#tab2-content .scrollspy-section {
height: 900px;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
#tab2-scrollspy {
position: fixed;
top: 300px;
}
#tab2-scrollspy li > a {
padding: 0;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background-color: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#tab2-scrollspy li > a:hover {
background-color: #AAA;
  }
#tab2-scrollspy li.active > a {
background-color: #444;
  }
```

Comment: You should post `app-shinyjs.js` and `app.css` files in order to reproduce your code.

Comment: @alessio I have just added the supporting files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is intended.**

What you experience here is a feature of Bootstrap, the [responsive breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). In its edge case: There is a minimum width for which all containers will span over the whole page. This is done mainly for websites to become mobile friendly, since i.e. a column that spans over a third of the device gets very narrow and can become really hard to read. And therefore it is intended, that "columns" get disbanded at a certain point.

If you really dont want this to happen, you have two options.

Either, knowing that this happens with bootstrap, you refrain from using columns and specify the div width youself, such that it is fixed no matter what.

Or you try to counter act the bootstrap css by including another style sheet. You can look through the bootstrap.css for *media queries* that are responsible for the breaks. And then copy the styles and apply them to the very small screen sizes. I took the liberty to create a css that would be sufficient for your cases, posted below:

### bs-no-break.css

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .navbar-right ~ .navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```