# How do I create a ShinyDashboard with a row of 4, 8, 4, 8 that will also scale properly if window is narrowed?

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a 4,8,4,8 ShinyDashboard that you can view here:

https://spangle.shinyapps.io/TDEC-O3/

Relevant dashboard layout code in R:

```
dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column),
    # CSS can be put here, needs "!important"
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
        .dygraph-legend {
      background: transparent !important;
      left: 0px !important;
        }
        .box-header h3.box-title {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
      .col-sm-6 {
     width: 12.5%;
      }
      .box { margin-bottom: 1px; } 
      [class*="col-lg-"],[class*="col-md-"],
      [class*="col-sm-"],[class*="col-xs-"]{
      padding-right:1px !important;
      padding-left:1px !important;
      }'))),
    
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('hendersonville'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot1", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('cedars'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot2", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('fairview'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot3", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('freels'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot4", height = 198))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box( title = "HV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot5", height = 151)),
      box( title = "HV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot6", height = 151)),
      box( title = "CL Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot7", height = 151)),
      box( title = "CL Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot8", height = 151)),
      box( title = "FV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot9", height = 151)),
      box( title = "FV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot10", height = 151)),
      box( title = "FB Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot11", height = 151)),
      box( title = "FB Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot12", height = 151))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('loudon'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot13", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('newmarket'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot14", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('kingsport'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot15", height = 198)),
      box(width = 3, title = textOutput('blountville'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot16", height = 198))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box( title = "LN Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot17", height = 151)),
      box( title = "LN Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot18", height = 151)),
      box( title = "NM Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot19", height = 151)),
      box( title = "NM Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot20", height = 151)),
      box( title = "KP Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot21", height = 151)),
      box( title = "KP Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot22", height = 151)),
      box( title = "BV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot23", height = 151)),
      box( title = "BV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot24", height = 151))
    ),
```

It works nicely in full screen, but if I view on mobile or narrow the window enough then the smaller graphs (row of 8) get squished to 12.5% of the screen, making them useless:

[image: Squished graphs]

If I don't restrict them to 12.5%, then I don't get the layout I want in fullscreen:

[image: without 12.5% styling]

I have another one that has a 2,4,2,4 layout that does not have this problem when I shrink the screen and I do not need to restrict it to 12.5%.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour for `fluidRows`. Please see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334376/9841389).

To avoid it we can e.g. use `splitLayout()` instead (Your css will need fine tuning):

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column),
    # CSS can be put here, needs "!important"
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
        .dygraph-legend {
      background: transparent !important;
      left: 0px !important;
        }
        .box-header h3.box-title {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
      .col-sm-6 {
     width: 12.5%;
      }
      .box { margin-bottom: 1px; }
      [class*="col-lg-"],[class*="col-md-"],
      [class*="col-sm-"],[class*="col-xs-"]{
      padding-right:1px !important;
      padding-left:1px !important;
      }'))),
    splitLayout(
      box(title = textOutput('hendersonville'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot1", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('cedars'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot2", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('fairview'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot3", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('freels'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot4", height = 198), width = 12)
    ),
    splitLayout(
      box(title = "HV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot5", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "HV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot6", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "CL Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot7", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "CL Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot8", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "FV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot9", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "FV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot10", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "FB Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot11", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "FB Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot12", height = 151), width = 12)
    ),
    splitLayout(
      box(title = textOutput('loudon'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot13", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('newmarket'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot14", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('kingsport'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot15", height = 198), width = 12),
      box(title = textOutput('blountville'), background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot16", height = 198), width = 12)
    ),
    splitLayout(
      box(title = "LN Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot17", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "LN Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot18", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "NM Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot19", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "NM Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot20", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "KP Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot21", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "KP Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot22", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "BV Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot23", height = 151), width = 12),
      box(title = "BV Hourly O3", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot24", height = 151), width = 12)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Furthermore, please see this article:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

and `library(gridlayout)` as an alternative:

https://rstudio.github.io/gridlayout/